# Binary file access function in Android device with C++Builder

Tags: android, c++, file, c++builder, rad-studio

In the past, I have developed a Windows mobile program that used C++ file access functions (`fopen`, `fwrite`, `fread`, `fseek`, ...) to access binary files.

Now, I need to transfer my program to an Android device. Is it possible to use the same file access functions with the C++Builder compiler?

If yes, how to do that?

If not, what functions can I use in C++Builder? Is there any sample that can be downloaded for reference?

```cpp
/*-------------hash2-------------*/
/*   Window         hash program                                     */
/* argument 1. data file name                                     */
/* argument 2. index file name                                    */
/* argument 3. item string                                        */
/* argument 4. total data string                                  */
/* argument 5. locate table (file positation) if tab  ==1 mean Query data */
/*                                            if tab  ==-1 mean append the data  */
/* if data append return 0 , if data exist return 1,if data full return -1,if not found return 2*/
/* if open file error return -2 */

WinCE_DLL_API    int _cdecl Hash2(char *DaTa_Fn,char *InDex_Fn,unsigned char *item,unsigned char *ttl_data,int *tab )
   {
      unsigned char *cmp;
      int i,ret;
      int nill=-1,inx;
      long sum,stm_loc,x,k,MAX_INX;
      HASH_HEAD hash_head;
      //union LONG_UC iconl;


      ret=f_read(&hash_head,sizeof(hash_head),DaTa_Fn,0L);
      if( !ret )
          return -2;  //if open file error return -2  , 2009/11/28

      MAX_INX=hash_head.MAX_REC/2;
      MAX_INX+=hash_head.MAX_REC;

      cmp=(unsigned char *)malloc(hash_head.TTLLEN+4);
      memset(cmp,'\x0',hash_head.TTLLEN+4);
      nill=-1;

      stm_loc=sum=0L;
      strcpy( (char *) cmp, (char *) item);
      for ( k = 1L, sum = 0L, i = 0 ; i < hash_head.ITMLEN ; i++, k++)
          sum += (long)item[i] * k * k * (k%10L + 1L);
      x = sum % hash_head.HASHNUM;
      //fprintf(temp,"%d\n",x);
      stm_loc = x * 4L;
      sum=stm_loc;

      ret=f_read(&inx,2,InDex_Fn,stm_loc);
      if( !ret )
          return -2;  //if open file error return -2  , 2009/11/28

      if ( inx == nill && *tab == nill )
      {
         if(hash_head.tab_bottom >= hash_head.MAX_REC || hash_head.inx_bottom >= MAX_INX)
           {
             free(cmp);
             return DATA_FULL;
           }

         f_write(&hash_head.tab_bottom,2,InDex_Fn,stm_loc );


         stm_loc = (long)hash_head.tab_bottom * (long)hash_head.TTLLEN+(long)hash_head.HEADLEN; /* tab_bottom && inx_bottom is 7 byte*/

         f_write(ttl_data,hash_head.TTLLEN,DaTa_Fn,stm_loc );

         *tab=hash_head.tab_bottom;
         hash_head.tab_bottom+=1;

         stm_loc=0L;
         f_write(&hash_head.tab_bottom,2,DaTa_Fn,stm_loc );

         free(cmp);
         return APPEND;
      }
      else
          if(inx== nill && *tab!= nill)
            {
              free(cmp);
              return NOT_FOUND;
            }
      else /* collision */
      {  while(1)
         {
            stm_loc = (long)inx * (long)hash_head.TTLLEN+(long)hash_head.HEADLEN; /* 4 byte of inxbottom + tabbottom */
            f_read(cmp,hash_head.TTLLEN,DaTa_Fn,stm_loc );

            i= Str_cmp(cmp+hash_head.start_byte,item,hash_head.ITMLEN);
            if ( i == 0 )
               {
                 memcpy(ttl_data,cmp,hash_head.TTLLEN);
                 *tab=inx;
                 free(cmp);
                 return DATA_EXIST ;
               }
            else
            {
               sum+=2L;
               f_read(&inx,2,InDex_Fn,sum );     /* get next index */
               if ( inx == nill && *tab!= nill )
                  {
                     free(cmp);
                     return NOT_FOUND;
                  }
               if ( inx == nill && *tab== nill )
               {
                  if(hash_head.tab_bottom >= hash_head.MAX_REC || hash_head.inx_bottom >= MAX_INX) /* could not append */
                    {
                      free(cmp);
                      return DATA_FULL;
                    }
                  f_write(&hash_head.inx_bottom,2,InDex_Fn,sum);
                  stm_loc = (long)hash_head.inx_bottom * 4L;
                  sum=stm_loc;
                  f_write(&hash_head.tab_bottom,2,InDex_Fn,sum );
                  sum+=2L;
                  f_write(&nill,2,InDex_Fn,sum );

                  hash_head.inx_bottom+=1;
                  stm_loc = (long)hash_head.tab_bottom * (long)hash_head.TTLLEN+(long)hash_head.HEADLEN; /* table */

                  f_write(ttl_data,hash_head.TTLLEN,DaTa_Fn,stm_loc);

                  *tab=hash_head.tab_bottom;
                  hash_head.tab_bottom+=1;

                  f_write(&hash_head.tab_bottom,2,DaTa_Fn,0L);
                  f_write(&hash_head.inx_bottom,2,DaTa_Fn,2L);

                  free(cmp);
                  return APPEND ;
               }
               else
               {
                  stm_loc = (long)inx * 4L;
                  sum=stm_loc;
                  f_read(&inx,2,InDex_Fn,stm_loc);
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }

/*--------F_read---------*/
WinCE_DLL_API int _cdecl f_read(void *buffer,int count,char *fn,long fpos )
{
  int num;
  FILE *fp;

  TCHAR  wsFileName[140];
  
  memset(wsFileName,0,sizeof(wsFileName));
  MultiByteToWideChar( CP_ACP, 0, fn , strlen(fn)+1 , wsFileName, sizeof(wsFileName)/sizeof(wsFileName[0]) );


  if ((fp= fopen( ANSItoUnicode( fn),ANSItoUnicode("rb"))) == NULL) 
  {
      return FALSE;
  }
  fseek(fp,fpos,SEEK_SET);
  num= fread(buffer,1,count,fp);
  fclose(fp);

  if (num == count) return TRUE;
  else              return FALSE;
}
/*--------F_append---------*/
WinCE_DLL_API int  _cdecl f_append(void *buffer,int count,char *fn )
{
  int num;
  FILE *fp;
  TCHAR  wsFileName[140];
 
  memset(wsFileName,0,sizeof(wsFileName));
  MultiByteToWideChar( CP_ACP, 0, fn , strlen(fn)+1 , wsFileName, sizeof(wsFileName)/sizeof(wsFileName[0]) );


  if ((fp=fopen( ANSItoUnicode( fn ), ANSItoUnicode("r+b"))) == NULL)
  {
      return FALSE;
  }
  fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
  num=fwrite(buffer,1,count,fp);
  fclose(fp);
  if (num == count) return TRUE;
  else              return FALSE;
}
/*--------F_write---------*/
WinCE_DLL_API int _cdecl f_write(void  *buffer,int count,char *fn,long fpos )
{
  int num;
  FILE *fp;

  TCHAR  wsFileName[140];
 
  memset(wsFileName,0,sizeof(wsFileName));
  MultiByteToWideChar( CP_ACP, 0, fn , strlen(fn)+1 , wsFileName, sizeof(wsFileName)/sizeof(wsFileName[0]) );


  if ((fp=fopen( wsFileName, TEXT("r+b") )) == NULL)
  {
      return FALSE;
  }
  fseek(fp,fpos,SEEK_SET);
  num=fwrite(buffer,1,count,fp);
  fclose(fp);
  if (num == count) return TRUE;
  else              return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you can't use standard C/C++ functions in a C++ compiler on Android? Did you even try the code on Android yet? Did you run into a problem with it?

Comment: Be aware that Embarcadero C++ currently only supports 32bit C++ for Android

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I am not yet to transfer my code from Visual Studio to C++ builder . I am just plan to transfer to RAD Studio , So ask here first. Thanks a lot.